# Could not load file or assembly iTextSharp.DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, itext

I am developing an application in vb.net sharepoint in which I generate PDF files with buttons
I'm using the itextsharp.dll library for PDF generation, the error is as follows, to make 'Debug' in the app all goes well, but when clicking on a button, the application ('Server Error in' / falls 'Application.')
reviewed the 'event viewer' and error me the following message:
"Exception message:. Could not load file or assembly 'iTextSharp, Version = 5.5.5.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of Its dependencies The system can not find the file specified."

I have the following: I have the DLL loaded into the 'bin / debug' folder and have added the corresponding reference
also attempt to load the DLL from C: \ windows \ microsoft.NET \ .... and nothing
 
took 3 days researching my problem and still can not find the error :(
ps: sorry for my English, I speak Spanish

Answer (score 1):

I've never used iTextSharp before, but in doing some searches online, it looks like you can use the [NuGet package manager to load iTextSharp into your project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/). This should take care of loading the appropriate references into your project.

Also, in checking out some iTextSharp examples online, it looks like you have to reference the correct iTextSharp libraries in your code, such as iTextSharp.text and iTextSharp.text.pdf.

I checked out [this example online](http://cjhaas.com/blog/2011/09/03/1-vb-net-itextsharp-tutorial-hello-world/) and after installing iTextSharp with Nuget, was able to get the example to work just fine.

Comment: thanks, this method by installing the dll with nuget works, but in a common application vb, my problem is to do this yourself in a vb.net application with sharepoint, if you try, you will display the same error: /